# Itemize or enumerate inside longtable

Tags: lists, longtable, tabularray

I have a long table with 10 columns and I would like to put some items inside cells and the table does not fit on the page.

[image]

```
\centering
\begin{longtblr}
    [
  caption = {Conteúdos programados},
  label = {tab:test},
]{
  colspec = {||c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c||},
  rowhead = 1,
  hlines,
  row{even} = {gray9},
  row{1} = {olive9},
} 
    \hline\hline
    Semana&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Horas}&\makecell{Unidade\\Temática}&Conteúdos&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Estratégias}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Avaliação}&Bibliografia \\
    \hline\hline     
    &Cont.&E. I.&&&\makecell{Actividades das\\horas de Contacto}&\makecell{Actividades das horas\\de estudo Independente}&T. Contacto&T. E. Independente&  \\
    \hline\hline
\end{longtblr}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please make your code snippet minimally compilable by indicating which document class you employ and which packages are needed to get the table-related code to compile. If there are any other packages that are essential for the appearance of the document, please tell us about them as well.